# Automatically retrieve EXE file version to embed in NSIS installer metadata

Tags: metadata, versioning, nsis

I am attempting to remove one more step in my application's release process by automatically retrieving versioning info from my executable (in this case, a .NET application).

Up to this point, I have been able to get by with a limited knowledge of NSIS, but I am quickly learning that this is not enough.

**Step 1: Declare version info in executable**

In AssemblyInfo.cs, I declare `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]`. This successfully makes the version info appear in the compiled executable (under "File version" and "Product version").

**Step 2: Retrieve version info from executable**

According to this [article on "GetFileVersion"](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetFileVersion), importing "FileFunc.nsh" allows you to retrieve version info from an executable.

Code used:

```
Section
    Var /GLOBAL version
    ${GetFileVersion} "C:\test.exe" $version
    ...
SectionEnd
```

**Step 3: Verify contents of function call**

Based on [section 5.1.7 of the documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.1.7), I should be able to print to the command line during compile time using the "!echo" command. The difference between printing the contents of a variable (or a constant, etc) still confuses me, so I have tried all four of these options:

```
!echo $version
!echo "$version"
!echo "${version}"
!echo ${version}
```

This results in:

```
$version (InstallScript.nsi:15)
$version (InstallScript.nsi:16)
${version} (InstallScript.nsi:17)
${version} (InstallScript.nsi:18)
```

**Step 4: Declare the installer metadata**

Based on [section 4.8.3](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.3), I should be able to add installer metadata via `VIProductVersion` and `VIAddVersionKey`.

```
VIProductVersion $version 
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "$version"
```

In the built installer, this adds the string "$version" into the specified fields.

---

Is there a `ToString()` equivalent in NSIS? How can I access a variable's contents? Does the print of the variable name mean that it has no contents? How can I verify that `GetFileVersion` is called correctly, executes correctly, and returns a value?

Comment: The reason this won't work is that the ${GetFileVersion} gets executed at runtime. You can't use the contents of a variable in a thing that gets fixed at compile time. You could do it with a preprocessing executable.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Can you expand this comment and your alternative into an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSIS - put EXE version into name of installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039024/nsis-put-exe-version-into-name-of-installer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: NSIS v3 now includes a [`!getdllversion`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#ppgetdllversion) preprocessor instruction, you only need the GetVersionLocal workaround if you are still using NSIS v2.

There are plans for a !getdllversion<strike>local</strike> in NSIS 2.47, for now you have to use this workaround:

```
outfile test.exe
requestexecutionlevel user

!macro GetVersionLocal file basedef
!verbose push
!verbose 1
!tempfile _GetVersionLocal_nsi
!tempfile _GetVersionLocal_exe
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'Outfile "${_GetVersionLocal_exe}"$\nRequestexecutionlevel user$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'Section$\n!define D "$"$\n!define N "${D}\n"$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'GetDLLVersion "${file}" $2 $4$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'IntOp $1 $2 / 0x00010000$\nIntOp $2 $2 & 0x0000FFFF$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'IntOp $3 $4 / 0x00010000$\nIntOp $4 $4 & 0x0000FFFF$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'FileOpen $0 "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" w$\nStrCpy $9 "${N}"$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'FileWrite $0 "!define ${basedef}1 $1$9"$\nFileWrite $0 "!define ${basedef}2 $2$9"$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'FileWrite $0 "!define ${basedef}3 $3$9"$\nFileWrite $0 "!define ${basedef}4 $4$9"$\n'
!appendfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}" 'FileClose $0$\nSectionend$\n'
!system '"${NSISDIR}\makensis" -NOCD -NOCONFIG "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}"' = 0
!system '"${_GetVersionLocal_exe}" /S' = 0
!delfile "${_GetVersionLocal_exe}"
!undef _GetVersionLocal_exe
!include "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}"
!delfile "${_GetVersionLocal_nsi}"
!undef _GetVersionLocal_nsi
!verbose pop
!macroend

!insertmacro GetVersionLocal "$%windir%\Explorer.exe" MyVer_
VIProductVersion "${MyVer_1}.${MyVer_2}.${MyVer_3}.${MyVer_4}"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "${MyVer_1}.${MyVer_2}.${MyVer_3}.${MyVer_4}"

page instfiles
section
sectionend
```

This macro:

1. Creates a temporary .nsi file
2. Compiles the temporary .nsi to a temporary executable
3. Runs the temporary .exe
4. Deletes the two files (.nsi and .exe)
5. Returns an array containing the version info of the specified executable.

Comment: There, I knew you'd do better, @Anders. That's why I didn't bother filling my comment out into an answer :-)

Comment: @Anders: Thank you for the answer. I was unable to work on this problem in the interim due to other priorities, but now I'm working on it again. From what I can tell, this macro creates a temporary nsi file, compiles it, runs it, and deletes the files. Is that correct?

Comment: @user664939 It also includes the result but yes that is correct

Comment: @Anders: Tested and works. I edited in a version of my comment into your post. Please remove or change it if you feel it is inaccurate.

Comment: Can someone explain how this is used please?

Comment: @MoonKnight What do you mean "how this is used"? The example uses it. But NSIS v3 has a command for it now so there is no need for this workaround in the first place anymore...

Comment: I don't see where a custom .exe path is used in the above. Can you provide a reference to the new way of doing this please?

Comment: @MoonKnight Look at the top of my answer for NSIS 3. For the macro when using NSIS 2 it is right there: !insertmacro GetVersionLocal "$%windir%\Explorer.exe" MyVer_ , just replace $%windir%\Explorer.exe with whatever path you want. You can change MyVer_ if you want as well...

Comment: Sorry about this. It's been a hell of a long day... Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 10):

Updated information:

NSIS now includes !getdllversion command which does the same thing. Usage:

```
!getdllversion "$%windir%\explorer.exe" expv_
!echo "Explorer.exe version is ${expv_1}.${expv_2}.${expv_3}.${expv_4}"
```

---

**UPDATE**: *!getdllversion* command is a "Compile Time Command", it's different from the *GetDLLVersion* instruction.
IMO it should have been named as *!getdllversionlocal* to prevent confusion, since it's similar to *GetDLLVersionLocal* instruction, not the *GetDLLVersion*

In the user manual included in NSIS 3.0a1 it says:

> 5.1.14 !getdllversion
>
> localfilename define_basename
>
> This is similar to GetDLLVersionLocal, only it stores the version
>   number in defines and can therefore be used anywhere, not just inside
>   functions and sections.
>
> ```
> !getdllversion "$%windir%\explorer.exe" expv_
> !echo "Explorer.exe version is ${expv_1}.${expv_2}.${expv_3}.${expv_4}"
> ```

Comment: `GetDllVersion` runs on the *target machine* running the installer.  He really wants `GetDLLVersionLocal`, which is evaluated on the building system.

Comment: @EricLaw: No, it's evaulated on the _building system_; from the NSIS User Manual: This is similar to GetDLLVersionLocal, only it stores the version number in defines and can therefore be used anywhere, not just inside functions and sections. Not: This section does't exist in online manual currently, only in user manual coming with the NSIS installation.

Comment: You're right-- but that's really odd. The NSIS.chm file included in NSIS3.0a has no such information, and says: `GetDLLVersionLocal - This is similar to GetDLLVersion, only it acts on the system building the installer.` It doesn't really make any sense that `GetDllVersion` runs on the building system, but testing suggests that it seems to be true.

Comment: GetDLLVersion instruction runs on the target machine, but !getdllversion command runs on the building system. Command should have been named as !getdllversionlocal

Comment: @EricLaw, I'm confused after seeing that you opened a ticket about this 4 years ago and thanked after !getdllversion is added in June. http://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/bugs/913/ . Am I missing something ?

Comment: :-) I simply keep forgetting that `!getdllversion` exists and does something different than `getdllversion`

Comment: I think it's named just `!getdllversion` because as a compile-time command it's impossible to run it in a non-local environment (the target machine). Maybe that was the reason...